# Exclude a file from Django's autoreload in runserver

Tags: python, django

I have a particular module that takes a little long to load, and is unlikely to change when running my Django server (let's call it `badmodule/badfile.py`).

However, when I run `python manage.py runserver`, the Django server will autoreload that file even if it hasn't changed. I'd like that file to only load once when the server is started, but not get reloaded again.

Comment: Does it really matter if the dev server reloads when this file is changed? The dev server doesn't take that long to reload

Comment: Well the whole point is that file in particular is really slow to load, so it slows down the whole reload. Let me rephrase the question.

Comment: What you're asking for is not trivial as every dependent module has to be loaded on every start. A slow loading app is always a bad thing, why is this module so slow to load?

Comment: It's for a third-party module that has to make a network call (usually takes 10s of ms). I agree it's bad practice, and a module import shouldn't result in a network call, but that's beyond my control.

Comment: Why does this third party package have to make a (10 second??) network call when imported and can you change this behaviour? Please provide some details if you can. Having this package as a dependency means that every instance of your app will have this issue and will have a knock-on affect for your deployments and scripting

Comment: By "10s of ms" I mean tens of milliseconds, not tens of seconds. I can look into changing the behavior, but I was hoping it would be easier to just tell Django to only load it once. It loads some configuration that is critical to the app but has to be stored remotely.

Comment: It's not about configuring Django, it's about changing the behaviour of your app and it's dependencies when it starts. Can you not give any insight into what this package is doing? A third party package that makes a network request on import seems very odd

Comment: try using Lazy of Django or importing the module dynamically.